# List all generators of the set $\{5^n\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a pretty simple abstract algebra problem; however, I want to ensure I understand fully.

I know $5$ is a generator of this set since applying $5$ to itself repeatedly produces the set; however, is $1/5$ also a generator? Since the operation is multiplication, I think I am getting myself confused.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: if I am meaning "group" instead of "set", I apologize for mixing those two up!

Comment: What is a generator of a set?

Comment: I am using Joseph Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra and the definition I am following is "...a group $G$ is cyclic if there is an element $a$ of $G$ such that $G =$ {$a^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}$}. Such an element $a$ is called a generator of $G$." This leads me to believe that both 5 and 1/5 are generators of my aforementioned set, but again I think I'm getting myself confused.

Comment: So, you are talking about **group** generators, not about **set** generators, whatever that is.

Comment: I apologize; I am mixing those words together. Algebra has never been my strong suit, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. More generally: if a subset $S$ of a group $G$ spans a subgroup $H$, then the set $\{g^{-1}\mid g\in S\}$ also spans $H$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $5$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ are both generators. You can also prove there are no more generators. If $|n|>1$ then $5^n$ can't generate the group since there is no $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $5=(5^{n})^m$.